# HttpGet with parameters using HttpWebResponse C#

Tags: c#, rest, c#-4.0, httpwebrequest, http-get

I'm trying to perform a GET with added parameters. I was previously using WebClient code which suddenly stopped working so I've decided to switch to using HttpWebRequest/HttpWebResponse. How do you go about adding parameters properly? I have a REST function that takes in two string parameters, but I can't get it to see them. Basically, how do I add multiple parameters to a GET call?

Here's my GET code (booksString is a comma-separated string of book ids):

```
string webAddress = "http://localhost:5000/stuff/address";

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(webAddress);
request.Headers.Add("bookIds", booksString);
request.Method = "GET";
request.Accept = "text/html";
request.KeepAlive = true;
request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
string text = "";
using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(),
             Encoding.ASCII))
    {
        text = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("text: " + text);
```

and here is my REST code:

```
public List<Book> GetBooks(string bookIds, string param2)
{
    Console.WriteLine("book IDs: " + bookIds + " " + param2);
}
```

Whenever I run this code `bookIds` is empty? How do I send multiple parameters and have my REST function recognize the data?

Comment: Try sending request with URL like  http://localhost:5000/stuff/address?bookIds=value&param2=value

Comment: Doesn't look like rest to me. Seems like a plain method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using URL encoding.

http://localhost:5000/stuff/address?bookIds={0}&param2={1}

Use string.format to fill the values and make the call.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the RestSharp Nuget Package, which encapsulates the HTTPWeb Request very neatly.

In that you can do this

```
var baseUrl = "http://localhost:5000/";
var resource = "stuff/address";
var api = new RestClient(baseUrl);
var request = new RestRequest(resource, Method.GET);
request.AddQueryParameter("bookIds", bookString);
request.AddQueryParameter("param2", value);
api.Execute(request);
```